# how to include css and js files to php template?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

i have built my simple template for php site.
the problem is that i don knw the nice way to include my css  and javascript files .

here is my **index.php** file

```
<?php
include'core/template.php';
$temp=new Template();
$settings=array("title","page_title","welcome_word");
$values=array("RIS - Home","Results Information System","Welcome to result 
               Information      system");
$temp->header($settings,$values);
$temp->footer();


?>
```

here is my **template.php** file

```
<?php
class Template {
public function header($setting,$values){
    $file=file_get_contents("http://localhost/RIS/src/header.php");
    $count=0;
    foreach ($setting as $setting) {
        $file=str_replace('{'.$setting.'}',$values[$count],$file);
        $count++;
    }
    echo $file;

}

public function footer(){
    $file=file_get_contents("http://localhost/RIS/src/footer.php");
    echo $file;
}
}




?>
```

here is my **header.php** file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{title}</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>{page_title}</h1>
            {welcome_word}
    </header>
    My contents goes here...
```

here is my **footer.php** file

```
<footer>
Copyright &copy; RIS 2013.
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

i have my css files and js files are in **assets folder**  so how do i include them in my template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use output buffers & include instead of file_get_contents, `include'core/template.php';` here is a blankspace missing.

In your case, why not just put the CSS and JS into `header.php` ?

Or if you want non-blocking, put CSS in header.php and JS in footer.php

Comment: thenx for advise, i think this will help

Answer (score 1):

For CSS files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{title}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/assets/yourcss.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>{page_title}</h1>
            {welcome_word}
    </header>
    My contents goes here...
```

and for javascripts:

```
<footer>
Copyright &copy; RIS 2013.
</footer>
<script src="path/to/assets/yourjs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Additional Information** Css files are called between head tags. But the reason of calling js files at the end of body is to ensure all DOM elements are instatiated.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use "file_get_contents", you can use "include_once" to include your footer file.

For your template, put a marker for the css, and build your css array in php then inject it to your marker.

Hope it helps.

Comment: include_once('path/to/footer.php'); For the loops, build an array for exemple with all your css files, then loop on it and build the css includes (<link href=""....>), then inject it like the rest in a marker like {css_head}